# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException в jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Всем привет. пытаюсь при помощи сервелета + jsp сделать генерацию таблиц по введённым числам.Но появляется вот такая ошибка, как я понимаю она появляется из-за того что массив начинает работать до того, как я введу числа и поэтому выдает ошибку, что я уже не пробовал, ничего не помогает
вот код сервлета

```
package app.servlets;

import app.entities.Table;


import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("views/add.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);

    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int age = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("name"));
        int age1 = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("pass"));
        req.setAttribute("page", age);
        req.setAttribute("page1", age1);
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

код jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Add new user</title>
</head>
<body>
</div>
<table border="1" >
<%

    for(int x=0;x<(int)request.getAttribute("page");x++){
        out.println("<tr>");
        for(int f=0;f<(int)request.getAttribute("page1") ;f++){
            out.println("<td>eq1</td>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }

%>
</table>

</div>
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="name"><br />
    <input type="number" name="pass"><br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

ну и index.html если нужна

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My super project!</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- header -->
<div>
    <h1>Super app!</h1>
</div>

<div>       <!-- content -->
    <div>    <!-- buttons holder -->

        <button onclick="location.href='/add'">Генерация таблицы</button>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

сама ошибка

```
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/views/add.jsp] at line [13]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/views/add.jsp] at line [13]

10: <table border="1" >
11: <%
12: 
13:     for(int x=0;x<(int)request.getAttribute("page");x++){
14:         out.println("<tr>");
15:         for(int f=0;f<(int)request.getAttribute("page1") ;f++){
16:             out.println("<td>eq1</td>");


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:593)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:482)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        app.servlets.AddServlet.doGet(AddServlet.java:18)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Root Cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.jsp.views.add_jsp._jspService(add_jsp.java:128)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        app.servlets.AddServlet.doGet(AddServlet.java:18)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: **Порвое:** не нужно в *doPost* вызывать *doGet*. **Второе:** оберни циклы *for* условием: `if(request.getAttribute("page") != null && request.getAttribute("page1")) {...}`

Comment: @notaProgrammer Я уже пытался через if сделать, но тогда не отрисовывается таблица, то есть, когда ввожу числа он все равно думает, что они null и не срабатывает if.

Comment: Ну тогда очевидно, что ты не передаешь значения. Я не увидел у тебя в форме атрибута `action` и маппинг сервлета к url-у, который задан в action.

Comment: Значения передаются, потому что если я цикл заменяю на ${page} , то на странице отрисовывется null, а после когда я выбираю число null меняется на это число. Я добавил if. Теперь другая ошибка) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/views/add.jsp] at line [17]

 if(request.getAttribute("page")!=null&request.getAttribute("page1")!=null){
17:     for(int x=0;x<(int)request.getAttribute("page");x++){
18:         out.println("<tr>");
19:         for(int f=0;f<(int)request.getAttribute("page1") ;f++){
20:             out.println("<td>eq1</td>");

Comment: Какой `null`? `age` и  `age1`, которые ты передаешь в качестве атрибутов запроса имеют примитивный тип.

Comment: про null что-то перепутал, вот сейчас я поменял цикл на ${page} ${page1} и после нажатия кнопки submit появляются числа которые я ввел, значит, что значения передаются, как я понимаю null появлялся, когда out.println(request.getAttribute("page"))

Comment: все, наконец, решил проблему. Программа потом ругалась, java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer  Я решил это костылями)                    if(request.getAttribute("page")!=null&&request.getAttribute("page1")!=null){ int i = Integer.parseInt((String) request.getAttribute("page"));
     int d = Integer.parseInt((String) request.getAttribute("page1"));
    for(int x=0;x<i;x++){
        out.println("<tr>");
        for(int f=0;f<d ;f++){
            out.println("<td>eq1</td>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }}